# NodeUtil unwrap method

Tags: java, jcr

What does the NodeUtil unwrap method do in this snipet and what is the effect on the Node:

```
Node node;
if (subMap.get(JcrConstants.JCR_UUID) != null && NodeUtil.unwrap(root) instanceof NodeImpl) {
         final Node unwrapped = NodeUtil.unwrap(root);
         node = ((NodeImpl) unwrapped).addNodeWithUuid(key, nodeType, 
         String.valueOf(subMap.get(JcrConstants.JCR_UUID)));
} else {
         node = root.addNode(key, nodeType);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two lines

```
final Node unwrapped = NodeUtil.unwrap(root);
node = ((NodeImpl) unwrapped).addNodeWithUuid(key, nodeType, 
         String.valueOf(subMap.get(JcrConstants.JCR_UUID)));
```

basically allow you to add a note with a specific UUID as opposed to the system generated one.